# List denies to be appended

Tags: python, list, append, freecad

Below is a portion of python code which is meant to work with [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) libraries. I can provide the full code if requested.

What's weird in this code is that appending to a list, `mr_fus.References`, does no effect on the size of the list. I also tried to append to a dummy list, `temp`, and its size returned as expected.

[Here](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/1baf5da3cfb24d9fcc1a1389cbd502f60002e7ab/src/Mod/Fem/femobjects/_FemMeshRegion.py) is the definition of `References`.

Although `type()` indicates that `References` is a list, to me, it looks like no ordinary list. I am curious if it is possible for a list to deny to add element to itself.

```
temp = [] # just for comparison
for i in range(1,len(App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces)):
    mr_fus.References.append((App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape, App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces[i]))
    temp.append((App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape, App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces[i]))

print(type(mr_fus.References)) # <class 'list'>
print(len(mr_fus.References)) # 0 # why??
print(len(temp)) # 18
```

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example though not minimal.

```
import sys
import math
import numpy

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/freecad/lib/')

import FreeCAD
import Draft
import Part
import BOPTools.JoinFeatures

doc = FreeCAD.newDocument('newdoc')

ZERO = 1e-10

def U(c, xl):

    u = c[5]

    if c[6] != 0:

        t = c[0] + c[1] * abs((xl + c[2]) / c[3]) ** c[4]
        if abs(t) <= ZERO:
            t = 0

        u += c[6] * t ** (1./c[7])

    return u;

class Fuselage:

    def H(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.4, 0.4, 1.8, 0.0, 0.25, 1.8]
        elif xl < 0.8:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.9:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 1.1, 1.5, 0.05, 0.2, 0.6]
        elif xl < 2.0:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -1.9, 0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 0.05, 2.0]

        return U(c, xl);


    def W(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.4, 0.4, 2.0, 0.0, 0.25, 2.0]
        elif xl < 0.8:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.9:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 1.1, 1.5, 0.05, 0.2, 0.6]
        elif xl < 2.0:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -1.9, 0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 0.05, 2.0]

        return U(c, xl);


    def Z(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.4, 0.4, 1.8, -0.08, 0.08, 1.8]
        elif xl < 0.8:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.9:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 1.1, 1.5, 0.04, -0.04, 0.6]
        elif xl < 2.0:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0]

        return U(c, xl);


    def N(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.4, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        elif xl < 0.8:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.9:
            c = [5.0, -3.0, -0.8, 1.1, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        elif xl < 2.0:
            c = [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 1.0, 1.0]

        return U(c, xl);

class Pylon:

    def H(xl):

        if xl < 0.8:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 0.4, 3.0, 0.0, 0.145, 3.0]
        elif xl < 1.018:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 0.218, 2.0, 0.0, 0.145, 2.0]

        return U(c, xl);


    def W(xl):

        if xl < 0.8:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 0.4, 3.0, 0.0, 0.166, 3.0]
        elif xl < 1.018:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 0.218, 2.0, 0.0, 0.166, 2.0]

        return U(c, xl);


    def Z(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.125, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.018:
            c = [1.0, -1.0, -0.8, 1.1, 1.5, 0.065, 0.06, 0.6]

        return U(c, xl);


    def N(xl):

        if xl < 0.4:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        elif xl < 1.018:
            c = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        return U(c, xl);


def yl(xl, phi, part):
    return r(part.H(xl), part.W(xl), part.N(xl), phi) * math.sin(phi)

def zl(xl, phi, part):
    return r(part.H(xl), part.W(xl), part.N(xl), phi) * math.cos(phi) + part.Z(xl)

def r(H, W, N, phi):
    a = abs(0.5 * H * math.sin(phi)) ** N + abs(0.5 * W * math.cos(phi)) ** N
    b = (0.25 * H * W) ** N
    return (b / a) ** (1./N)


xm = numpy.linspace(0.00001, 2, 10)
xp = numpy.linspace(0.40001, 1.018, 10)
p = numpy.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 10)

def makepart(part, x):
    polygons = []
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        points = []
        for j in range(len(p)-1):
            points.append(FreeCAD.Vector(x[i], yl(x[i], p[j], part), zl(x[i], p[j], part)))
        points.append(points[0])
        polygons.append(Part.makePolygon(points))

    loft = Part.makeLoft(polygons)
    cap1 = Part.Face(polygons[0])
    cap2 = Part.Face(polygons[-1])
    shell = Part.Shell(loft.Faces+[cap1, cap2])
    Part.show(shell)
    return shell

fuselage = makepart(Fuselage, xm)
pylon = makepart(Pylon, xp)

# join-connect fuselage and pylon
# let's call the joined object 'heli'
heli = BOPTools.JoinFeatures.makeConnect(name = 'Connected')
heli.Objects = [App.ActiveDocument.Shape, App.ActiveDocument.Shape001]
heli.Proxy.execute(heli)
heli.purgeTouched()

# make heli a solid
s = Part.Solid(Part.Shell(heli.Shape.Faces))
Part.show(s)

# make a sphere
sphere = Part.makeSphere(2,FreeCAD.Vector(1,0,0))
Part.show(sphere)

# cut heli from sphere
cut = sphere.cut(s)
Part.show(cut)

# extract seem of sphere
import CompoundTools.CompoundFilter
f = CompoundTools.CompoundFilter.makeCompoundFilter(name = 'CompoundFilter')
f.Base = App.ActiveDocument.Shape004
f.FilterType = 'window-volume'
f.Proxy.execute(f)
f.purgeTouched()

# make a line from seem of sphere to heli
line = Draft.makeWire([heli.Shape.Vertex27.Point, App.ActiveDocument.CompoundFilter.Shape.Vertex1.Point])

# split heli and line
import BOPTools.SplitFeatures
split = BOPTools.SplitFeatures.makeBooleanFragments(name= 'BooleanFragments')
split.Objects = [App.ActiveDocument.Shape004, App.ActiveDocument.Line]
split.Mode = 'Standard'
split.Proxy.execute(split)
split.purgeTouched()

#export to step
#split.Shape.exportStep("robin.step")

import ObjectsFem
mesh = ObjectsFem.makeMeshGmsh(FreeCAD.ActiveDocument, 'FEMMeshGmsh')
mesh.CharacteristicLengthMin = 0.5
mesh.CharacteristicLengthMax = 0.5
mesh.ElementDimension = 3
FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Part = FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.Shape004

mr_fus = ObjectsFem.makeMeshRegion(FreeCAD.ActiveDocument, FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.FEMMeshGmsh, 0.5, 'fus')
mr_outer = ObjectsFem.makeMeshRegion(FreeCAD.ActiveDocument, FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.FEMMeshGmsh, 1.0, 'outer')
mr_fus.CharacteristicLength = 0.7

temp = []
for i in range(1,len(App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces)):
    mr_fus.References.append((App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape, App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces[i]))
    temp.append((App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape, App.ActiveDocument.Shape004.Shape.Faces[i]))

print(type(mr_fus.References))
print(len(mr_fus.References))
print(len(temp))
```

EDIT: About FreeCAD version:

OS: Ubuntu 19.04
Word size of OS: 64-bit
Word size of FreeCAD: 64-bit
Version: 0.18.4.
Build type: Release
Python version: 3.7.3
Qt version: 5.12.2
Coin version: 4.0.0a
OCC version: 7.3.0
Locale: English/United States (en_US)

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: My guess is that it’s a property and regenerated on every access. Check `type(mr_fus).References`.

Comment: @Ry- `type(mr_fus).References` returns `type object 'FeaturePython' has no attribute 'References'`